# Swagger-ui anchor link to model definitions

Tags: javascript, anchor, swagger, swagger-ui

Is it possible to access a model definition of via swagger-ui directly via an anchor?

In the example page http://petstore.swagger.io/ I see that the anchor works for a groups of endpoints, e.g.
http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet.

Hovering the mouse over a model description shows me an anchor (e.g. `#/definitions/Category` for the `Category` model), but 
http://petstore.swagger.io/#/definitions/Category does not bring me there.

If I inspect the elements, I see a real link to anchor `pet`:

`<a class="nostyle" href="#/pet"><span>pet</span></a>`

while for `Category` this is a *model-hint*:

`<span class="model-hint">#/definitions/Category</span>`

So I wonder if anchoring models is supported at all..

Answer (score 3):

Swagger UI does not support permalinks for schemas/models. There's an existing feature request:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1369