# Render model in Method description in Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I would like to refer to a model in the method-description by linking to an item in the "Models"-section at the bottom of the page. I'm using Swashbuckle in c# if that makes a difference.

Contrived example:
".. Operation expects a [[HouseModel]]-object" which, if clicked, either renders it as a model, or, also acceptable, links it to the HouseModel model in the "Models"-section at the bottom of the UI-page.

I should mention I've played with the $ref-properties, trying to link to the correct component, but it doesn't render correctly. It renders the $ref-line verbatim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [Swagger UI anchor link to model definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46827462/113116)

Comment: I think it does. Seems it's not supported yet. Thanks, Helen.